# how to pronounce "in that"

Tags: pronunciation, conjunctions, phonetics

I am wondering how to pronounce **"in that"**, where *in that* is a synonym for *because*. I have little understanding of reduction. Is it right to pronounce it /inə/?

Answer (score 1):

You would pronounce 'in that' as two separate words in the normal way that those two words are pronounced. Why would you want to 'reduce' it?

Comment: I learned that 'that',as a function words, is often reduced to pronounced as /ðə/ or /ðət/.However, I found that several English listening materials pronounce 'in that' as  /inə/

Comment: Reduction is what makes speech sound natural. If you pronounce each word separately, you will end up sounding robotic.

Comment: PS: that's not to say that **every** word can be reduced, but we tend to say "coulda" instead of "could have" and so on. The rule of thumb is that content words are generally stressed and function words are generally reduced.

Comment: It is a matter of register, to some extent. I speak with less contraction at a business or academic meeting or in a court of law than I would over drinks or blunts with my homies. Nobody at the meetings or in the courts thinks I am a robot.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would not understand what "/inə/" was supposed to mean. First, I would best understand /ɪ/ as the first syllable, same as "in". At least where I have lived, people would also retain all the consonants.

Overall, if speaking quickly, I would probably say it as /ɪn.ðət/. I'd say it as one word, and with the vowel of "that" reduced to a schwa, but it would still be recognizable as the original words.